# Pandas: splitting data frame based on the slope of data

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data frame

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'entity':[5,7,5,5,5,6,3,2,0,5]})
```

[image]

**Update:** I want a function If the slope is negetive and the length of the group is more than 2 then it should return True, index of start and end of the group. for this case it should return:  result=`True`, index=`5`, index=`8`

1- I want to split the data frame based on the slope. This example should have 6 groups.

2- how can I check the length of groups?

[image]

I tried to get groups by the below code but I don't know how can split the data frame and how can check the length of each part

**New update**: Thanks Matt W. for his code. finally I found the solution.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'entity':[5,7,5,5,5,6,3,2,0,5]})
df['diff'] = df.entity.diff().fillna(0)
df.loc[df['diff'] < 0, 'diff'] = -1

init = [0]
for x in df['diff'] == df['diff'].shift(1):
    if x:
        init.append(init[-1])
    else:
        init.append(init[-1]+1)
def get_slope(df):
    x=np.array(df.iloc[:,0].index)
    y=np.array(df.iloc[:,0])
    X = x - x.mean()
    Y = y - y.mean()
    slope = (X.dot(Y)) / (X.dot(X))
    return slope
df['g'] = init[1:]

df.groupby('g').apply(get_slope)
```

**Result**

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    0.0
4    NaN
5   -1.5
6    NaN
```

Comment: Could you provide your expected output?

Comment: I updated the request

Comment: Shouldn't group 5 be split into further 3 groups, since the magnitude of the gradients are different?

Comment: @kerwei No, in this problem,  only detecting slops with negative and positive value is important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the difference and `bfill()` the start so that you have the same number in the 0th element. Then turn all negatives the same so we can imitate them being the same "slope". Then I shift it to check to see if the next number is the same and iterate through giving us a list of when it changes, assigning that to `g`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'entity':[5,7,5,5,5,6,3,2,0,5]})
df['diff'] = df.entity.diff().bfill()
df.loc[df['diff'] < 0, 'diff'] = -1

init = [0]
for x in df['diff'] == df['diff'].shift(1):
    if x:
        init.append(init[-1])
    else:
        init.append(init[-1]+1)
df['g'] = init[1:]
df
   entity  diff  g
0       5   2.0  1
1       7   2.0  1
2       5  -1.0  2
3       5   0.0  3
4       5   0.0  3
5       6   1.0  4
6       3  -1.0  5
7       2  -1.0  5
8       0  -1.0  5
9       5   5.0  6
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to present another solution that doesn't require a for-loop:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'entity':[5,7,5,5,5,6,3,2,0,5]})
df['diff'] = df.entity.diff().bfill()
df.loc[diff < 0, 'diff'] = -1
df['g'] = (~(df['diff'] == df['diff'].shift(1))).cumsum()
df
```